# Instagram - anonymous access?

Tags: instagram-api

I'm just now having a hard time understanding the instagram API. Is there really no way to write a simple plugin that displays images based on latitude and longitude? The media/search endpoint needs authentication and I'm not wanting to have my users authenticate to instagram before they can see these images. But from what I read I need an access token and I'll only get the access token after doing a full OAUTH2 routine.
Thanks!

Comment: to access instagram API you need developer token, it is not the same as user's login/pass

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought as well :) Seems it's not so easy to find such a token in the developer section then ;)